# Segmentation fault by writing in a 2D Array

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, calloc

I have a small memory access problem in my program and I do not find the error, maybe someone could help me.

I have created a new type to store rgb color values.
That type looks like:

```
typedef struct pixel {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
} pixel;
```

In my main program I create with calloc a 2D dynamically array, to store the red color information’s.

```
pixel **pixelvalue = (pixel **) calloc(imginformation.width, sizeof(pixel));
for (i = 0; i < imginformation.width; i++) {
    pixelvalue[i] = (pixel *) calloc(imginformation.height, sizeof(pixel));
}
```

After that I call my function, which read the color values and who should safe them to the array. The function gets as parameter the array.

```
ReadFile(file, imginformation (Stuff like height and so one), pixelvalue (The calloc array));
```

In that function I try to write the values with

```
pixelvalue[i][j].r = (unsigned char)fgetc(in);
```

Here I get the memory access error, what did I wrong?

**Edit**

Hi, first of all sorry about the missing language, I was a little bit tired yesterday :).

To understanding, I created an array of pixel and the elements are pointing to another array of pixel? Something like `[Point to another 1D array pixel]`?

With pixel `**pixelvalue = calloc(imginformation.width, sizeof(pixel *));` I create `imginformation.width` numbers of pointers from type pixel and each pointer show to pixel, right?

It would be awesome if you could explain it a little bit more, if I’m wrong. I would really like to understand it.

@carl-norum What do you mean with:

> "you shouldn't be casting the return values of calloc(). Doing so can
>   hide bugs with #include that could come back to bite you down the
>   road".

? I use the alloc space as parameter for a function, not as return value.

Thanks for your help!

Greetz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really making a 2D array, you're making an array of pointers that point to arrays of pixels.  That means your first `calloc` call should allocate enough space for pointers, not for pixels:

```
pixel **pixelvalue = calloc(imginformation.width, sizeof(pixel *));
```

You didn't tag your question with a language, but assuming it's C (based on your `typedef`, which wouldn't be necessary in C++), you shouldn't be casting the return values of `calloc()`.  Doing so can hide bugs with `#include` that could come back to bite you down the road.

**Edit:**

You asked a couple of follow-up questions.  The first has been answered pretty well by several other answers, I think, but I'll try to summarize.  The way you're doing the allocation, you are first going to allocate an array of pointers - each of those pointers is going to point to one row of your array.  The rows themselves then need to be allocated - space for each `pixel` object goes there, and the pointers to the rows are stored in the first array of pointers.

Your second question, bout the return value from `calloc()` is pretty straightforward.  If you cast the return value, you can hide implicit declaration bugs from yourself.  Since the return type of `calloc` is `void *`, if you do something like:

```
my_ptr = calloc(1, 2);
```

Everything works nicely.  Now imagine that you didn't include `stdlib.h`, and therefore had no prototype of `calloc()` in your translation unit.  That would lead the compiler to assume the signature of `calloc()` to be `int calloc(int, int)`, which isn't true.  The same line of code above would throw you a warning about assuming a default signature for that function.  Using a typecast like you have in your code will mask that warning and you might never know you were missing that `#include` line.

Comment: Hi, thanks your solution works fine. Now I have a few understanding problems, see me Edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the diagram for an explaination[image]

So you first create the array of `pixel *` using calloc. Populate that array using `calloc` with `pixel`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! So first i create all the pointer, for example the height and every element show to a pixel for the width. Thank you!

Comment: Taz - it helps to use a diagran to rationalise things in your mind

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
pixel **pixelvalue = (pixel **) calloc(imginformation.width, sizeof(pixel));
```

`pixelvalue` is a pointer to a pointer to pixel - your typedef.

You need to write

```
pixel **pixelvalue = calloc(imginformation.width, sizeof(pixel *));
```

instead.

Comment: Yea, your right as well as @carl-norum. Please see me **Edit**, I'm did I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The other posters have correctly identified that you should be allocating your first block of memory in units of `pixel*` instead of in units of `pixel`.

But why does this problem cause segfault?

On a 32 bit machine, your pixel struct as defined above takes 3 bytes, but a pointer takes 32 bits (4 bytes).

That is,

- `sizeof(pixel) == 3`
- But `sizeof(pixel*) == 4`

So you're only allocating 75% of the memory you need. When accessing the bottom quarter of the image, you'll access memory you never allocated.

(On some 64 bit platforms, the problem definitely only gets worse. On some 16 bit platforms, you might be able to get away with this, although it'd still be sloppy)

Comment: Yes, should be. You understand why this issue is occurring, right? (See Ed Heal's fine diagram)