# Segmentation fault while dynamic allocation of 2D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I am a newbie to C programming (relearning it after a long time) . I am trying to dynamically allocate memory to a 2D array using malloc. I have tried following the answers on stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121906/segmentation-fault-by-writing-in-a-2d-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556242/a-segmentation-fault-error-with-2d-array). But I still get the segmentation fault.

My code is as below

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocate2DArray(int **subset, int a, int b)
{
  subset = (int **)malloc( a * sizeof(int *));
  int i,j;

  for(i = 0 ; i < a ; i++)
    subset[i] = (int *) malloc( b * sizeof(int));

  for(i = 0 ; i < a ; i++)
     for(j = 0 ; j < b ; j++)
        subset[i][j] = 0;
}

int main()
{
  int **subset;
  int  a = 4, b = 4;
  allocate2DArray(subset, a, b);
  int i,j;
  for( i = 0 ; i < a  ; i++)
  { 
     for( j = 0 ; j < b ; j++)
     {
        printf("%d ", subset[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
  }
}
```

When I comment the lines to print the array, it doens't give any error and program executes without segmentation fault. Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Function arguments in C are passed *by value*. So your function call in `main` does nothing (except for leaking memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OneMoreLevelOfIndirection):

```
void allocate2DArray(int ***p, int a, int b)
{
    int **subset;
    *p = (int **) malloc(a * sizeof(int *));
    subset = *p;

// ...
allocate2DArray(&subset, a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks @ctn ..that worked. I also tried it without using the int **subset. like this..                                                             `*p = (int **)malloc(a * sizeof(int *));
 for( i = 0 ; i < a ; i++)
 {
   (*p)[i] = (int *)malloc(b * sizeof(int));
 }
 for(i = 0 ; i < a ; i++)
  for(j = 0 ; j < b ; j++)
    (*p)[i][j] = i+j;
}`
Couldn't get why this is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: @quirkystack For me `void allocate2DArray(int ***p, int a, int b) { int i, j; *p = (int**)malloc(a*sizeof(int
*)); for(i=0; i<a; i++) (*p)[i] = (int*)malloc(b*sizeof(int)); for(i=0; i<a; i++) for(j=
0; j<b; j++) (*p)[i][j] = i+j; }` with `main() { /* ... */ int **subset; allocate2DArray(&subset, a, b); /* ... */ }` is working

Comment: my mistake.. didn't add paranthesis around *p in my actual program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must pass a `int ***subset` to the allocation function. This because arguments are passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
void allocate2DArray(int ***subset, int a, int b)
```

and this:

```
allocate2DArray(&subset, a, b);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. While compiling it gives two warnings: (1) `assignment to ‘int ***’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int **’` (2) `assignment to ‘int **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int *’`. And gives segmentation fault when executing.

Answer (score 0):

By using `int **subset;` it does not become 2D array. It is still 1D storage and just pointer to pointer.

2D array means each element of a pointer buffer must point to a buffer which is suggested by ctn.
He has suggested ***ptr and *ptr is malloced which created 1st dimension of buffer.
Now when you call allocate2DArray() again subset is allocated memory which create second dimension. Which validate my above statement - each element of pointer buffer must point to a buffer.

so now with suggested code -

```
 *p = (int **) malloc(a * sizeof(int *));
```

created an array each element of which point to buffer 'subset' which altogether create a true 2D array.